# Android visual animation on screen touch

Tags: android, effect

I am coding a game in android and i want to play a kind of animation when user touch the screen. I know that there is probably tutorials to do this. But i don't really know what is the name of this effect so i don't know what to search.So all my searches were vain.The effect is like the one you could see in this image([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sg5pM.jpg)  ) in Magic Tiles 3.
Thank you.

Comment: These are called particle effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to switch to unity :) Native Android is not really made for that kind of stuff.. More constructive answer:

Quick googling showed couple of particle libraries, for example check [this](https://github.com/jinatonic/confetti)

Running particle like animations natively is not really a recommended way to go since since you will be running around 10-15 animations in a loop (which will have a really hard impact on your apps performance). If you still want to go this way, it would be the best to create  [animated drawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation) or use [lottie](https://airbnb.design/lottie/) animated image views and set as your layout background